# WSO2 - TOTP google authenticator with QR code

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I implemented the following tutorial on the latest version of wso2 identity server 6.1.0: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/mfa/2fa-totp/ When i run my application, i get the login form, then i am redirected to google sign in page where i write my email and password.

This flow is working fine, however, in the tutorial, they mentioned that i should get a QR code to be scanned and then the otp should be retrieved from google authenticator application.

Why i am not getting the QR code page? is there anything i should implement on the web application level? or is there anything else i should do on the identity server level?

Identity provider config:

[image]

Service provider config:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think here you have 2 steps.

1. Google authenticator
2. TOTP

AFAIK this TOTP as the 2nd step will not work since your first step is a federated authenticator. Identity Server trusts federated authenticator. If you configure multiple options as the first step (one is not a federated authenticator), then you will see the TOTP page.

Configure the following steps.

1. Username & Password + Google
2. TOTP

When you select username and password, you will see the TOTP page.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i added to my question some images explaining the used configuration. I am not sure how to differentiate between Google authentication and totp, but i tried to follow as much as possible this url: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/mfa/2fa-totp/ and used the same google configuration detailed under another link from wso2 doc. Can you please guide?

Comment: @user666 can you mention the experience that you are planning to provide? That will be easier to suggest the steps.

Comment: The experience is as follows: user logs in using his username and password, he is then asked to provide an OTP, he opens his google authenticator app, scans a QR code to enroll, then get an OTP from the app and enters it > successfully signed in. The next time, he will not see a QR code but just otp which he will get from the google auth app.

Comment: can you please help

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring the following authentication steps.

1. Username and password
2. TOTP

you can find the steps [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/mfa/2fa-totp/#configure-totp-as-the-second-factor).